# How to define a function pointer pointing to a static member function?

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"

class Person;
typedef void (Person::*PPMF)();

// error C2159: more than one storage class specified
typedef static void (Person::*PPMF2)();  

class Person
{
public:
    static PPMF verificationFUnction()
    { 
        return &Person::verifyAddress; 
    }

    // error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 
    // 'void (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'PPMF2'
    PPMF2 verificationFUnction2()               
    { 
        return &Person::verifyAddress2; 
    }
private:
    void verifyAddress() {}

    static void verifyAddress2() {}
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Person scott;

    PPMF pmf = scott.verificationFUnction();
    (scott.*pmf)();
    return 0;
}
```

Question: I need to define a function pointer PPMF2 to pointing to a static member function verifyAddress2. How can I do it?

```
#include "stdafx.h"

class Person;
typedef void (Person::*PPMF)();
typedef void (Person::*PPMF2)();

class Person
{
public:
    static PPMF verificationFUnction()
    { 
        return &Person::verifyAddress; 
    }
    PPMF2 verificationFUnction2()
    { 
        return &Person::verifyAddress2; 
    }
private:
    void verifyAddress() {}

    static void verifyAddress2() {}
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Person scott;

    PPMF pmf = scott.verificationFUnction();
    (scott.*pmf)();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any reason why this question got downvote. Is it wrong to ask this question? +1 to compensate it!

Comment: ^+1 - i think its a valid question

Comment: @Nawaz, the definition/usage of PPMF is correct. However, I would like to do the similar action for static member functions and VS2010 gave me the errors which are updated in the original question.

Comment: In both versions, you have a static function returning the address of a non-static function. I would expect the compiler to fuss inside `static PPMF verificationFUnction()` that you need an instance to refer to `return &Person::verifyAddress;` since `verifyAddress` is not static.

Answer (score 45):

A pointer to a static member function is just a normal function pointer. `typedef void (*PPMF2)()`. You assign it to a static member function like you assign any function pointer, only that the static member function is inside the class scope:

```
PPMF2 myfunc = &MyClass::StaticMemberFunc;
```

Comment: @Xeo, it doesn't work for me the similar problem:error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'void (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'PPMF2'

Comment: @q0987: I don't have any problem compiling that: `Person p; PPMF2 pf = p.verificationFUnction2();`. Have you changed your `typedef` of `PPMF2`?

Comment: @Xeo, which version of VS did you use? I am using VS2010.

Comment: @q0987: Same. VS2010 `10.0.30319.1 RTMRel`

Comment: @Downvoter: Anything wrong with my answer? If yes, please tell me so.

Comment: @Xeo, I have posted a second code snippet, please copy and paste to your vs2010 and then you will see the errors.

Comment: @q0987: Like I said, you have to change your typedef of PPMF2 to `typedef void (*PPMF2)()`. A static member function isn't very different from a free function, only the scope is different.

Answer (score 7):

About static member function guarantees:

С++ ISO/IEC 14882 2003-10-15 says that

> 5.2.2 There are two kinds of function call: ordinary function call and member function 57) (9.3) call....
>
> 57) A static member function (9.4) is an ordinary function.

Theoretically static-member-functions can have another calling convention.
But standart allow us to leverage on such thing...

Answer:
typedef void (Person::*PPMF2)() => typedef void (*PPMF2)()

Answer (score 2):

If the function is static it does not require a (implicit) `this` pointer to be invoked. Therefore, a pointer to a static member function is not the same as a member function pointer:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

class Person;
typedef void (Person::*PPMF)();
typedef /*static*/ void (*PPMF2)();

class Person
{
public:
    static PPMF verificationFUnction()
    { 
        return &Person::verifyAddress; 
    }
    PPMF2 verificationFUnction2() 
    { 
        return &Person::verifyAddress2; 
    }
private:
    void verifyAddress() {}

    static void verifyAddress2() {}
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Person scott;

    PPMF pmf = scott.verificationFUnction();
    (*pmf)();
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

removed the offending static from the typedef.

Comment: Change the `PPMF2` typedef to `typedef void (*PPMF2)();`

Comment: Right, I overlooked the static in the typedef, I edited the answer.

Comment: This still has a static function `verificationFUnction` returning the address of a non-static function `verifyAddress` which isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
class A
{
private:
    int x,y;
    static int a;
public:
    A()
    {
        x = 10;
        y = 11;
    }
    ~A()
    {

    }

    void displayNonStatic()
    {
        cout<<x<<"  "<<y<<endl;
    }

    void displayStatic()
    {
        cout<<a<<endl;
    }
};

int A::a = 12;
int main()
{
    typedef void (A::*NonStatic)(void);
    typedef void (A::*Static)(void);
    A a1;

    NonStatic _nstatic = &A::displayNonStatic ;
    Static _static = &A::displayStatic;

    // Always make sure that call to the pointer to the member functions is made within the context of the instance.

//Correct way to call the pointer within the context of the instance " a1 " .
    (a1.*_nstatic)();
    (a1.*_static)();
//Error case given below, the pointer is not called within the context of the instance
  // (*_nstatic)(); ->error
  // (*_static)(); ->error
    getchar();
}
```

Refer to the  [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72c1dfd.aspx) for more information.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I believe that your static pointer is incorrect, it should not have A:: in the type.