# C++: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'void (*)()' with an rvalue of type 'void'

Tags: c++, function, opengl, methods, glut

I'm using GLUT with C++ and I'm calling a function called `glutDisplayFunc` with a single argument of the type `void (*)(void)`. For some reason, when I use the following C++ method from one of my classes:

```
void EventHandler::Render(void) { ... }
```

It throws this error:

```
cannot initialize a parameter of type 'void (*)()' with an rvalue of type 'void'
```

Which seems to give me the thought that my C++ method isn't declared to properly comply with the argument type `void (*)(void)`. What can I do to make my method work with this function parameter?

Answer (score 5):

A C++ method is not a normal function.  It won't convert to a normal function pointer.  You didn't show your actual code, but I'm assuming you did something like:

```
glutDisplayFunc(EventHandler::Render)
```

You need to make `Render` a `static` method if you want to use it this way.  Otherwise declare a free function and use that.

Comment: Then it's ok: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500057/how-to-define-a-function-pointer-pointing-to-a-static-member-function

Comment: Declared as `static` and it works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately using static invkoes undefined, compiler dependent behavior. See my answer on the very same topic asked just yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18656082/524368

Comment: I don't see anything about `static` in your answer.

Comment: @CarlNorum: See my comment(s) to the other answer.