# struct pointer function points to other function of other struct

Tags: c++, struct, c++14, function-pointers

I was wondering if is possible to point a function of other structure into of a  structure:

Example:

```
typedef struct
{
    int func(int z)
    {
        return z * 2;
    }
} sta;

typedef struct
{
    int(*this.func)(int);
} stah;


int main()
{
    sta sa;
    stah sah;

    sah.func = &sa.func;

    return 0;
}
```

it's possible this in a struct?

Comment: In your example you're not using anonimous struct, because you giving them name

Comment: @DenisSheremet my bad.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500057/how-to-define-a-function-pointer-pointing-to-a-static-member-function#answer-5500070) is possible solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration of `func` should look like this:

```
int(sta::*func)(int);
```

Or, alternatively:

```
using my_type = int(sta::*)(int);
my_type func;
```

This is easier to read: `my_type` is an alias for the type *pointer to a member function of `sta` that gets an `int` and returns an `int`*.
`func` is nothing more that a data member having type `my_type`.

In order to assign an actual pointer to member function to `func`, you can do this instead:

```
sah.func = &sta::func;
```

You can then invoke it as it follows:

```
(sa.*sah.func)(0);
```

Comment: the problem is that sta is imaginary, how would be in memory address?

Comment: there any form?

Comment: @nikomaster `sta` is a well defined class in your example. What does it mean _is imaginary_??

Comment: i means for reverse engineering, example:

Comment: hooking the method of structure as: sah.func = 0xFFFFF that points to &sta.func;

Comment: @nikomaster Do you mean something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/57dd7230121a775f)? Let me know and I'll put it in the answer, adding more details.

Comment: some like this: [link]http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b656b6b7b9da5f6

Comment: @nikomaster No, if you want use a pointer to function instead of a pointer to member function, you must define your member methods as `static`. As an example, see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dad70a55567cbf40).

Comment: then isn't possible hook a method form a structure in the memory?

Comment: other thing, i've post a address and compiles without problems.

Comment: works my method, i've searched the function with ida and using the address the code compiles without problems, at the same time without the function func(); being non-static.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for a pointer to method is:

```
&T::f
```

Where `T` is a type declaring a method `f`. Note that to be called, the pointer must be bound to an instance of `T`, because the value of the pointer represents an offset to the beginning of an instance in memory.

In C++14, you may consider `std::function`:

```
#include <functional>

struct sta
{
    int func(int z)
    {
        return z * 2;
    }
};

struct stah
{
    std::function<int(int)> func;
};


int main()
{
    sta sa;
    stah sah;

    sah.func = std::bind(&sta::func, &sa, std::placeholders::_1);

    return 0;
}
```

You can also use lambdas instead of `std::bind`:

```
int main()
{
    sta sa;
    stah sah;

    sah.func = [&sa](int z) { return sa.func(z); };

    return 0;
}
```

See [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), and [`std::placeholders`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders) on cppreference.com.

Answer (score 0):

After trying and trying, the solution it was something like this:

Example:

```
typedef struct 
{
    int a;

    int SomeFunc(int a)
    {
        return a * 4;
    }

} somst;


typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int (*HGetValX)(int);
} hst;


int main()
{
    hst* a;
    hst decfunc; // New instance
    somst b;

    decfunc.HGetValX = (int(*)(int))0x421C10; // memory address, or &b.SomeFunc; | &b.SomeFunc; Produces warnings.
    b.a = 20;

    a = (hst*)&b;


    cout << decfunc.HGetValX(4) << b.SomeFunc(4) << a->a <<  endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Finding memory address**

[image: Ida decompilation]
then the code compiles without warnings, the objective is hook the structure with their functions.